# Spark MLLib Collobarative filtering Implicit Feedback: TypeError: reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, collaborative-filtering

I'm trying to use Spark MLlib for building Implicit feedback recommender system. I start with running the code from the tutorial on MovieLens dataset in this link https://databricks-training.s3.amazonaws.com/movie-recommendation-with-mllib.html. The code runs successfully. Then  I run the code in this link https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/mllib-collaborative-filtering.html#explicit-vs-implicit-feedback with test dataset for explicit feedback. It runs good. Then I give my dataset which would be of the form UserID, MovieID, rating. Since it's implicit feedback, rating would be either 1 or 0. I run the same code in the second link but using model = ALS.trainImplicit(ratings, rank, numIterations, alpha = 0.01).  I get the following error: spark-1.1.0/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 760, in reduce
    return reduce(f, vals)
TypeError: reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value.

I see there is no vals argument in the code written in second link. Where is the error coming from and how do we solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you're not going to get a Python error if the error happened in the mllib because most part of the code for the `trainImplicit` is written in Scala (the Python part is just a wrapper for the Scala code). I believe that this error in the `reduce()` is due to some pre-processing or something that you're doing in the `ratings` RDD and due to the lazy evaluation, it will throw the error only when using it inside the `trainImplicit` method.